# Impossible hyperbolic integral

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, hyperbolic-functions

I'm quite good with integral calculation, very rarely happens that I'm not able to solve an indefinite integral. I've tried for 7 days to solve this monster but in the end, I surrendered to this beast.

I'm sure that it has a solution because it was a challenge from my calculus professor. Unfortunately, he didn't give the solution of this integral. It has been unsolved for years, since 7 days ago when I found it in my old notebook.

Can some expert help me?

$$\int { \frac { \sinh { x }  }{ \sqrt { 2\cosh { x+2 }  }  }\frac { 1+\sqrt { \frac { \sqrt { \cosh { x } +1 } +\sqrt { 2 }  }{ \sqrt { \cosh { x } +1 } +2\sqrt { 2 }  }  }  }{ 1-\sqrt [ 3 ]{ \frac { \sqrt { \cosh { x } +1 } +\sqrt { 2 }  }{ \sqrt { \cosh { x } +1 } +2\sqrt { 2 }  }  }  }  } dx$$

Comment: I'd start with the hyperbolic trigonometric identity $$\sqrt{\cosh x + 1} = \sqrt{2} \cosh \frac{x}{2} .$$

Comment: @Leprep98 Note if you let $y = \sqrt [ 6 ]{\frac { \sqrt { \cosh { x } +1 } +\sqrt { 2 }  }{ \sqrt { \cosh { x } +1 } +2\sqrt { 2 }}}$, then your second factor becomes $\frac{1+y^3}{1-y^2} = \frac{(1+y)(1-y+y^2)}{(1+y)(1-y)} = \frac{1-y+y^2}{1-y} = 1 + \frac{y^2}{1-y}$. Also, $\frac{y^2}{1-y}$ = \frac{y^2 - 1 + 1}{1-y} = -1 -y + \frac{1}{1-y}$. I haven't checked or worked out a solution so I don't know if this will help, but I believe it's at least something to consider.

Comment: Just setting $u$ to be the argument of $\sqrt[6]{\cdot}$ in John's answer transforms the integral into one of an algebraic function in $u$, but it doesn't look immediately tractable.

Comment: @Leprep98 Unfortunately, the $5$ minute timeout didn't let me fix my MathJax error in what I added in my comment above. I was trying to state that $\frac{y^2}{1-y} = \frac{y^2 - 1 + 1}{1-y} = -1 - y + \frac{1}{1-y}$. Thus, adding $1$ gives $-y + \frac{1}{1-y}$.

Comment: @Leprep98. There are points on which I totally agree : *monster* and *beast* !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As suggested in comments, let $x=2 \cosh ^{-1}(t)$ to end with
$$I=-2\int\frac{
   \left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{t+1}{t+2}}-\sqrt[6]{\frac{t+1}{t+2}}+1\right)}{\sqrt[6]{\frac{t+1}{t+2}}-1}\,dt$$

Now
$$\sqrt[6]{\frac{t+1}{t+2}}=y \implies t=\frac{1-2 y^6}{y^6-1}$$ makes
$$I=-12 \int\frac{ y^5 (y^2-y+1)}{(y-1) \left(y^6-1\right)^2}\,dy=-12 \int \frac{y^5}{y^5-y^3-y^2+1}\,dy$$
$$y^5-y^3-y^2+1=(y-1)^2 (y+1) \left(y^2+y+1\right)$$
 Partial fraction decomposition of the integrand leads to
$$-\frac{12y^5}{y^5-y^3-y^2+1}=\frac{4 (y+1)}{y^2+y+1}-\frac{7}{y-1}-\frac{2}{(y-1)^2}+\frac{3}{y+1}-12$$ and the final result (hoping no mistake)
$$I=\log \left(\frac{(y+1)^3 \left(y^2+y+1\right)^2}{(y-1)^7}\right)-12
   y+\frac{2}{y-1}+\frac{4 }{\sqrt{3}}\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 y+1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$$

Comment: Amazing work thank you so much.
You are correct, I've checked personally your steps and I got the same final expression

Comment: @Leprep98. *Amazing*, not really but interesting for sure. Try to combine the logarithms and the arctangent to make it more compact. By the way, you are very welcome !

Answer (score 5):

First make the substitution $y=\cosh x,$ then simplify the radicals by removing radicals from all denominators, to obtain the simpler $$\int\frac{\sqrt {2y+2}}{2y+2}\frac{\sqrt{(y-7)(y-3-\sqrt{2y+2})}}{\left({(y-7)^2(y-3-\sqrt{2y+2})}\right)^{1/3}}\mathrm d y.$$ Then make the substitution $2y+2=z^2.$ The integral becomes $$\int\left(\frac{z^2-8-2z}{z^2-16}\right)^{1/6}\mathrm d z.$$ Note that $$\frac{z^2-8-2z}{z^2-16}=1-\frac{2}{4+z}.$$ Can you complete it now? OK, seems I need to add that you only need make the substitution $$w^6=\frac{z^2-8-2z}{z^2-16},$$ so that the integral becomes $$12\int\frac{w^6\mathrm d w}{(1-w^6)^2},$$ which is elementary.

Comment: I did not go through your steps but I suspect that the result of the last integral *could* be an hypergeomtric function.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici No. It's elementary. Just make the substitution $$w^6=\frac{z^2-8-2z}{z^2-16}.$$ Perhaps I'll add this to my answer for clarity.

Comment: Then, you result is much simpler than mine.